# Spark integration with Zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Does Spark have integration with Zookeeper? I want to read configuration information from Zookeeper in Spark, without using Apache Curator. My question is if with Spark's Java API you can obtain this.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check out this [Spark Zookeeper integration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#high-availability) documentation ?

Comment: Well this is not what I need. I need to write some custom parameters in Zookeeper(nodes with children) and load them in Spark. Just what Curator does.